# Scraper returns null result

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Im trying to build a scraper that get the URL for free games of the epic games store

[image]

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",}
result = requests.get("https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/free-games?sessionInvalidated=true", 
headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')
urls = []
links = []
urls = soup.find('div', {'class': 'CardGrid-group_c5363b6a'}).find_all("a")
return urls
```

[image]
however it keeps returning null and I cant see what is wrong?

Comment: that might be fetched, rendered data, did you try printing `print(result.content)` and see if that data is in there? I found some json with free games in it, notably gta5: https://store-site-backend-static.ak.epicgames.com/freeGamesPromotions?locale=en-US&country=US&allowCountries=US

Comment: first check what you get in `result.content`. Maybe it has different class name. Some portals use different random names for classes in every execution.

Comment: you shows different class in code and different class on image. use other method to recognize element or use regex to recognize class with random name.

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to create these elements but `requests`/`BS` can't run JavaScript

Comment: is there any way of getting the data with a different technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to add elements but `requests`/`BeautifuSoup` can't run `JavaScript`

But as usually JavaScript reads data from URL which you can find in `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`,  filter: `XHR`) and you can use it to read data in JSON format - so you don't need `BeautifulSoup`

```
import requests

url = 'https://store-site-backend-static.ak.epicgames.com/freeGamesPromotions?locale=en-US&country=PL&allowCountries=PL'

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.json()

#print(r.text)

for item in data['data']['Catalog']['searchStore']['elements']:
    print(item['title'])
    offers = item['promotions']['promotionalOffers']
    for offer in offers:
        print(offer['promotionalOffers'][0]['startDate'])
        print(offer['promotionalOffers'][0]['endDate'])
```

Result

```
Mystery Game
Grand Theft Auto V
2020-05-14T15:00:00.000Z
2020-05-21T15:00:00.000Z
```

You woould have to digg in `data` to get other details.

**BTW:** Maybe you will have to use different values for `country` and `allowCountries`

Comment: Thats perfect thank you. Is there any tutorial you would recommend on this, Im struggling with more advance web scraping.

Comment: I don't know tutorials. I use only Google to find solutions for some problems. And some elements I learned before I started scraping - ie. when I was creating sockets in C/C++ (sockets, TCP, IP), or web pages in PHP (HTTP protocol, JavaScript/AJAX, web servers). Maybe only module `scrapy` I learned from [documentation](https://scrapy.org/), and `Selenium` from [tips](https://elementalselenium.com/tips) and [newsletter](https://elementalselenium.com/)

Comment: With the JSON, it doesnt contain a link to the actual site, just the description, for my solution I need to get the links of the games. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you mean https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/product/grand-theft-auto-v ? What is the problem to add game name to `https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/product/` ? I'm not sure but probably all games have similar url.

Comment: or maybe `"https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/product/" + item['productSlug']`

Comment: it works for gta, hopefully it'll work the future :D